# Populate a listbox from another listbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I wish to have two listboxes in the form of a columns. The left listbox should contain my reference items, the right listbox would start empty. I want to be able to double click on the items in the left listbox and have them appear in the right listbox.

I think this should be a simple task and I see it done in many places, but I can't find any examples of how to do it.

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript. Also, maybe you fail to get a working example because you were searching list when the word is listbox (or select multiple).

Comment: Luiggi, I am well aware that java and javascript are very different. I have also made many different searches before posting here. Your condemnation may please you, but is however unhelpful to everyone else!

Comment: You may say you know, but the way you posted your question shows that you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do this and follow the logic

the html part.

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option value="1">Fruit</option>
<option value="2">Animal</option>
<option value="3">Bird</option>
<option value="4">Car</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" id="select2">
<option value="1">Banana</option>
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="1">Orange</option>
<option value="2">Wolf</option>
<option value="2">Fox</option>
<option value="2">Bear</option>
<option value="3">Eagle</option>
<option value="3">Hawk</option>
<option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

the javascript part.

```
$("#select1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
});
```

So you will see that if you choose something from listbox1 it will change the listbox2. i hope i helped you